# Is it possible to use a Google TV device without a TV connection?

Tags: google-tv

With the price of the Logitech Revue having dropped, I am interested in using the Google TV device purely for the (internet) functionality of the Android platform.

Since a "Cable or Satellite set top box with HDMI out" is listed as a requirement I am wondering if the device can be used without the HDMI input being connected.

I am aware that this might remove the TV functions that are at the core of the device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you will be able to use the Logitech Revue Google TV unit without the Set-Top Box.  I am doing this with the Sony BlueRay Player w/GTV.  During the set-up process simply skip the section for setting up the TV provider and you should be all set.

Here is a [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tuXZdDkIuQc) video of a Revue functioning without a cable or satellite STB.

Comment: I happen to use it primarily as a UPnP client.  My internet connection is not that fast, so I download many of the youtube videos to my media server and watch it from there.  Also, I have cable, but not HDMI capable.